# How to represent SE

Tags: r, graphics, geom-bar

I'm using R studio to make a graphic using `ggplot` and `plyr` libraries as follow to calculate mean and SD:

```
data_summary <- function(data, varname, groupnames){
  require(plyr)
  summary_func <- function(x, col){
    c(mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE),
      sd = sd(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))
  }
  data_sum<-ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
                  varname)
  data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean" = varname))
  return(data_sum)
}
```

To represent the bar plot:

```
ggplot(datossummary, aes(x=Treatment, y=Phosphatase, fill=Treatment)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",color="black", width=0.4) +   scale_fill_manual(values=c("lightpink2", "lightpink2", "lightblue2", "lightblue2", "lightsalmon", "lightsalmon", "lightcyan4", "lightcyan4", "mediumpurple1", "mediumpurple1")) + theme_light() +
  ggtitle("Phosphatase") +
  xlab("Treatment") +
  ylab("CE") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Phosphatase-sd, ymax=Phosphatase+sd), width=.2, position=position_dodge(.9))
```

I want to represent SE instead of SD, but I cannot find how to calculate it without do it in the data set.

I tried this; using 'se' instead of sd;

```
data_summary <- function(data, varname, groupnames){
  require(plyr)
  summary_func <- function(x, col){
    c(mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE),
      se = se(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))
  }
  data_sum<-ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
                  varname)
  data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean" = varname))
  return(data_sum)
}
```

But I got this error:

> Error in se(x[[col]], na.rm = TRUE) : could not find function "se"

I also dont know how to calculate 'se' for a data frame (not individual values, introduced manually by me), if I knew I guess I can name it using `se <- ...` and include it in the `geom_bar` script.